# Does the category of directed systems have enough injectives?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be an abelian category with enough injectives.  Let $\mathscr{C}_A$ denote the abelian category of directed systems of objects of $\mathscr{C}$ indexed by $A$.  Does $\mathscr{C}_A$ have enough injectives?

If $\{C_\alpha\}$ is an object of $\mathscr{C}_A$, then for each $\alpha \in A$, there is an injective object $I_\alpha$ and a monomorphism $C_\alpha \to I_\alpha$.  One might hope that there is a monomorphism $\{C_\alpha\} \to \{I_\alpha\}$, but $\{I_\alpha\}$ does not appear to even be an object of $\mathscr{C}_A$: if $\alpha \leq \beta \leq \gamma$ in $A$, by using the definition of injective object and that $\{C_\alpha\}$ is a directed system, we do get morphisms $f_{\alpha\beta}:I_\alpha \to I_\beta$, $f_{\beta\gamma}:I_\beta \to I_\gamma$, and $f_{\alpha\gamma}:I_\alpha \to I_\gamma$, but these are not unique, so we cannot expect that $f_{\beta\gamma}f_{\alpha\beta}=f_{\alpha\gamma}$.

What might be another approach?

Comment: If $\mathcal{C}$ is a Grothendieck-Category the claim would follow from more general observations, since functor categories with values in a Grothendieck category are Grothendieck categories, which all habe enough injectives.

Comment: The fact that those have enough injectives can e.g. proved directly via transfinite induction like Grothendieck originally did in his Tohoku paper or by using that Grothendieck categories are exactly quotients of categories of modules over a ring with localizing subcategories (this is the Gabriel-Popescu-Theorem) and that the existence of injective hulls is preserved under quotients with localizing subcategories.